# How is the frequency vector being derived?

Tags: fft

I am having a hard time understanding how the frequency vector is being derived in this code. I would appreciate any guidance from anyone.

```
 Frv = linspace(0, 1, fix(numel(FTSignal)/2)+1)*Fn;
```

Comment: What are FTSignal and Fn ?

Comment: Any more answers required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> linspace(0, 1, fix(numel(FTSignal)/2)+1) $\tag{1}$

"$y =$ linspace(x1,x2,n) generates n points. The spacing between the points is (x2-x1)/(n-1)."

So in the above statement it is generating fix(numel(FTSignal)/2) points between 0 and 1 that are equally spaced

> Frv = linspace(0, 1, fix(numel(FTSignal)/2)+1)*Fn;

This generates Frv with just equation (1) scaled/multiplied by Fn

**Edited**: the FFT signal can usually be represented by half of the total FFT coefficients, since FFT of a real signal is symmetric around mid point, it is uniquely represented by half the coefficients. Adding 1 is for the DC frequency. Take an example an FFT of length 16, is represented by 8+1 coefficients. The "fix" function is present to handle FFT of odd length signal, so that they can be rounded to an integer value. Since these FFT values have been generated under the normalized scale of 0 to 1, it is then normalized by Fn, which can be $\pi$ or $F_s/2$, where $F_s$ is sampling frequency

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer but I am still confused. I guess I want to know in simple terms what the function is doing  why do we devide by FFT of the signal by 2 and why do we add 1? also why do we multiply by the Uniquist frequency Fn?

Comment: I have added further clarification in.the answer

Answer (score 0):

On signals of length $2N$, FFT yields equally $2N$ coefficients. Among them (up to a constant), two sets of $N-1$ coefficients are (normally complex) conjugate symmetric (let us call those **AC**  for the set with increasing positive frequency index), the two last ($2N-2(N-1) = 2$) coefficients are real:

- the average, DC-component or 0-frequency (**DC**)
- the highest or Nyquist-component (**NC**)

So, in some FFT implementations, and Matlab notably, the output vector is ordered as:

```
DC / (N-1) AC / NC / [(N-1) AC flipped and conjugate]
```

So your code grabs the first $2N+1$ coefficients, and scales their indices to make up a frequency axis from DC to Nyquist.

Nota: on odd-length signals, the NC coefficient is not present.