# unsymmetric fft in matlab

Tags: matlab, fft, dft, frequency-domain, time-frequency

This is the FFT of a 4khz sin signal. I wonder why the negative part and positive part of X axis is not symmetrical?

[image]

```
Amp = 0.3;
freqHz = 4000;
fsHz = 160000;
dt = 1/fsHz;
t = 0:dt:1600*dt;
sine = Amp * sin(2*pi*freqHz*t);
t = 0:1600
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(t,sine)

y1 = sine;
Fs = 160000;                   % samples per second
N = length(y1);            % samples
dF = Fs/N;                 % hertz per sample
f = -Fs/2:dF:Fs/2-dF + (dF/2)*mod(N,2);      % hertz
Y1_fft = fftshift(fft(y1))/N;
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(f , (abs(Y1_fft)) - min((abs(Y1_fft))),"o");
legend(num2str(i))
shg;
```

Comment: @LaurentDuval Nothing important. I removed it.

Comment: Why did you pick `Fs/2-dF + (dF/2)*mod(N,2)` as the upper bound of your frequencies? You should start with `0:N-1` as the frequencies, then scale those into the values you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wonder why the negative part and positive part of X axis is not symmetrical?

The data is symmetrical. The problem is that you have an odd FFT length and hence your frequency grid does NOT include the Nyquist frequency and you construct the frequency vector incorrectly. It should be `f1 = -(Fs/2-dF/2):dF:(Fs/2-dF/2);`

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the FFT coefficients can be found in an answer to the post [How is the frequency vector being derived?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/67261/15892).  Basically, they are arranged as:

```
DC / (N-1) AC / (NC) / [(N-1) AC flipped and conjugate]
```

with:

- DC: the average, DC-component or 0-frequency (real)
- AC: the set of generic coefficients with increasing positive frequency index (complex in general)
- (NC): the highest or Nyquist-component (real), only when the data length is even (thank you Hilmar)

Comment: Not for odd FFT lengths. An odd length frequency grid does not include Nyquist.